# Newely explained concepts in .net Framework 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

We have developed our website(Business users website) in .net Framework 2.0 Our client us to 
migrate to .net Framework 3.5. 
I am not interested in developing the same thing in both the frameworks.

Please anyone tell me some of the new features like card space, work flow, presentation foundation concepts in .net framework 3.5 and how we will use this in real time environment.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, not an answer, but .NET 3.5 is fully backwards compatible with 2.0. Just load the old project, change the framework, and away you go. No code conversions or anything like that.

Comment: You've really got to be tackling a specific domain problem to use Workflow Foundation, and Presentation Foundation you won't find much use for in a web application (especially since 3.5 SP1 broke headless rendering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can migrate your website to .Net 3.5 without requiring any code changes.  Depending on the language you are using there are several new features in 3.5 that can greatly simplify your code.  This does not have to be an all or nothing proposition.  I would recommend that you take advantage of the features that make sense for new code but leave the old code as is until there is time/money to convert it.  Some of the new features include:

Linq (Linq to SQL and Linq to XML being the predominant variants), Auto-Implemented Properties, implicit typing, object initializers, collection initializers, anonymous types, lambda expressions, and extension methods are the major language new features.